# What does the word “repultrigue” mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

What does the word “repultrigue” mean? I can't find this word in dictionaries and I googled it,  returning only two results about one same article. [In A Startling Episode 705, 'Mad Men' Meets 'Three's Company' And 'The Walking Dead'](https://www.forbes.com/sites/allenstjohn/2014/05/12/in-a-startling-episode-705-mad-men-meets-threes-company-and-the-walking-dead/#115a47f64e6f)

The word appears in the last of the second paragraph：

> But in an unsettling Episode 705, (spoiler alert) the biggest moments didn’t need words: the actor's reactions told you everything you needed to know. The look on Don’s face when he realized that Megan and Amy were really serious about the ménage a trois? Is there an English word for his mixed emotions?  Horrifuson? Repultrigue?

Comment: It's a made-up word, probably combining "repulse" and "intrigue".

Comment: @1006a Yes. The predecessor word in the review is "Horrifusion". They are known as "portmanteau" words - like e.g. brunch - a combination of breakfast and lunch; or Oxbridge, combination of Oxford and Cambridge.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) of "repulsion" and "intrigue". The author is awkwardly combining conflicting emotions for comic effect.